# using ifelse statement with 3 conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Below is the code I used to populate the Winner column with the team name of the winning team. However, for games that end in a draw, as seen in the image below, it always shows the away team's name. I am fairly new to doing this and could not figure out how to add a third condition. How can I edit the code so that it reads "draw" when a game ends in a draw?

```
Matches1 <- mutate(Matches, Winner = ifelse(home_team_goal_count > away_team_goal_count, home_team_name, away_team_name))
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 3):

Without data, here's a stab:

```r
library(dplyr)
Matches1 <- mutate(Matches,
  Winner = case_when(
    home_team_goal_count > away_team_goal_count ~ home_team_name,
    home_team_goal_count < away_team_goal_count ~ away_team_name,
    TRUE ~ "TIE"
  )
)
```